# Searching a table column with a specific word

Tags: sql-server, search

Let's say I have a table with two columns:

```
ID, FullName
```

And I have the following records in it:

```
John Bob Smith
John Bobby Smith
```

My problem is:

I want to return only the row that contains the matching word "Bob", and I don't want to return any rows that contain similar words like "Bobby"

When I search using :

```
Select * 
From Table1 
Where FullName like '%bob%'
```

I get the two rows which is wrong.

```
Select * 
From Table1 
Where FullName = 'Bob'
```

this return no rows at all.

```
Select * 
From Table1 
Where FullName like 'Bob'
```

this also does not return any rows.

I tried to use different wildcards but nothing works, I also tried the `CHARINDEX` and the `PATINDEX` but they do not return the needed results too.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE FullName LIKE '%Bob%'
  AND FullName NOT LIKE '%Bobby%'
```

Or perhaps you mean to avoid any `Bobby` and `Bobban` and `Boby` and `Bobbie`, etc...:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE FullName = 'Bob'             --- just Bob
   OR FullName LIKE 'Bob %'        --- starts with Bob
   OR FullName LIKE '% Bob'        --- ends with Bob
   OR FullName LIKE '% Bob %'      --- middle name Bob
```

This will miss however rows with `'John Bob-George Smith'` and `'John Bob. Smith'`, etc. If you want such extended functionality, an SQL function that splits strings as proposed by Albin is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, I saw Albin's answer on Regex but your answer worked for me just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are no built in functions in SQL server to compare whole words.

If you are on SQL Server you can either create a [CLR UDF to create a regex method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) or create a regular [SQL function to split strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql) .